# Trying to display welcome username when user logs in

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have been searching for the answer for days but nothing I try works,  I have tried adding a variable into the header link, adding php to the html, adding a session variable but nothing works.

I am trying to get when a user logs in for the first time they will be directed to landing_first and on that page it will say welcome "username" and then when they log out and log back in again they will be redirected to the landing_second.html which will say Welcome back "username". But nothing I seem to try is working!Really would appreciate some help

Here is the code that I am using in my login.php

```
   if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    // this creates a hashed password which will need to be inserted into the `zz_login` table
    // $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $sql = "SELECT user_id, `password` FROM zz_login WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

    if(!is_bool($result)) {
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        mysqli_free_result($result);

       if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])) {
        if(session_start()) {
            /* expire in 1 hour */ 
            // needs to be ahead of header - only add cookie when user is logged in
            setcookie("user_id", $user['user_id'], time() + 4600,'/~B00657633/Final%20Year/COM559/Major%20Project/startbootstrap-creative-gh-pages/');
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            // Check if whether a person has made any holiday reservations
            $userId = $user['user_id'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM zz_upload_itinerary WHERE user_id=$userId";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
              header('Location: ../landing_second.html?message=welcome back ' . $_SESSION["$username"]);// Redirect to the second page 
            }else{
               header('Location: ../landing_first.html?message=welcome ' . $_SESSION["$username"]);// redirect to the first page
            } 
            if(!empty($_GET['message'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']);
        } else {
            die('error session couldn`t be initialised');
        }
    } else {
        $fmsg = "Invalid Username/Password";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'd start by checking for errors, via php's error reporting and `mysqli_error($conn)` on the queries.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The queries are fine though as the user is able to log in ok, and be directed to what ever screen.

Comment: Just curious... You have the following logic: "If they have made an entry in zz_upload_itinerary, redirect to "landing_second.html", otherwise if they have NOT made an entry in itinerary table, go to landing_first.html" - That's what your code says. Is that valid? I thought the pages were supposed to be switched around. My second issue is that you are trying to use echo "<li>..." right after your header('location...); You can't use an echo after header(location).. It does not work.

Comment: The `header` sends the user elsewhere so the `echo '<li><a href="#">Welcome'. $_SESSION["$username"] . '</a></li>';` is never seen. Set the welcome message in a session variable then output it on the page they land on, or use a `GET`.

Comment: @Nerdi.org Sorry, I am just use to looking at the code, the comments are wrong. When ever a user has added something to the db they go to the landing_second after they log in again, if not they go to the landing_first. How do I display welcome username then? If I cant use echo?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @chris85 How do I do this? Would you be able to add an answer below displaying the code?

Comment: `header('Location: ../landing_second.html?message=welcome ' . $_SESSION["$username"]);/` do URL encoding on the username and the `welcome ` bit. Then also do escaping on the page you send them to so XSS can't be executed. `if(!empty($_GET['message'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']);` I think would do it, assuming you made `.html` executable as PHP. I cant test so i dont want to post as answer if that works let me know and can move it later.

Comment: @chris85 thanks, so if I add this here, is that right?  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                  header('Location: ../landing_second.html?message=welcome ' . $_SESSION["$username"]);// Redirect to the first page 
      if(!empty($_GET['message'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']);
                }else{
                   header('Location: ../landing_first.html');// redirect to the second page
                }

Comment: @chris85 can you please see updated question, i have no idea why it isnt working and how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Using `$_SESSION['userId'] = $user['userId']` will display the ID of the user from the database, but if you'd like to display the username of the user on the page then you should say, `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`

then, you would be able to call the session here or any where the session instance is running

i.e

```
 echo '<li><a href="#">Welcome'. $_SESSION["username"] . '</a></li>'
```

Comment: I changed the session but as nerdi.org pointed out I am not able to use echo after the header location. But I am still having problems

Comment: This is the answer. You just do it on another page, not during the same request. If you insist on doing this the hard way, you must initialize your setting each time without fail or `$_SESSION` won't be enabled.

Comment: @tadman I don't know what you mean. Do I do the echo part in the html so eg landing_first.html?

Comment: You can tell the client to redirect *or* you can display HTML content, not both. Normally you set the session variable, redirect, and then on the subsequent page show the session content.

Comment: @tadman I have updated my question to the code I have at the minute, could you please tell me what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: @tadman can you please reply to me. I am getting undefined variable session in my new php file. I have no idea what I am doing wrong and need it fixed in the next two hours because I have a deadline then. Please please please help me

Comment: That sounds like a new problem unrelated to this one, which means it should be a separate question. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting to html pages and sending those pages the welcome messages.
I would suggest that this is your problem (unless those pages are handled via htaccess but I suspect not based on your code).
Those welcome pages should really be PHP pages and should have the code;

```
<?PHP
echo "Welcome back ".$_SESSION["username"];
?>
```

Comment: i am getting an undefined variable _SESSION

Comment: Have you added the line;

    `session_start();`

at the top of each PHP file?